# What can I replace INTERSECT with in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I use SQL Server 2000 and I need to use "intersect" but with this SQL Server version I can't - so what should I use to have the intersection between two tables?

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, why are you even still using SQL Server 2000?

Comment: Have you tried using an INNER JOIN?

Comment: EXISTS might be what you are looking for..

Comment: You could possibly use a **more recent version** of SQL Server ..... this one is way past dead and non-supported .....

Comment: I have to use sql sever 2000 because my promoter asked me that I have no choice and also under win xp hhhh
For inner join somebody told me about it but it does not work please give me an example. I have two tables s1 and s2 I must have the intersection between them

Comment: i know it's an old version but i have no choice for know

Comment: Win xp??? wow!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intersect gets the matching results in both tables, comparing all columns returned by the queries, which must be the same for both sides of the intersect.

I believe these two will both work in 2000, but I'm not positive about the first one.  The first one is preferred because it does not have to perform a distinct sort.  You'll want to replace the '*' with just the columns you want to include, and you'll need to put all of those columns in the WHERE/ON clause respectively.

1. ```
   SELECT *
   FROM s1
   WHERE EXISTS 
   (
   SELECT 1
   FROM s2
   WHERE s1.Col1 = s2.Col1
   --All columns included here
   AND s1.ColN = s2.ColN
   )
   ```
2. ```
   SELECT DISTINCT s1.*
   FROM s1
   INNER JOIN s2
   ON s1.Col1 = s2.Col1
   --All columns included here
   AND s1.ColN = s2.ColN
   ```

Comment: they give the same result but

Comment: they give the same result but 'SELECT  s1.mat
FROM s1
INNER JOIN s2
ON s1.mat = s2.mat and s1.sex = s2.sex and s1.sauv = s2.sauv and s1.anet = s2.anet and s1.ocode = s2.ocode '      and     'SELECT  s1.mat
FROM s1
INNER JOIN s2
ON s1.mat = s2.mat ' does not give the same result .so should i precise all the columns that exist in the tabels s1  and s2 ? an thnkds for your annswer @Wes H

Comment: Intersect compares all of the columns in the result set.  You will need to do the same by listing every single column in your join/where.  Note, if you are using the join approach and there is more than 1 match, you will get duplicates.